# Anydesk connect Linux to Windows and transmit super key

Tags: linux-mint, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote

I have Anydesk installed on both my **Windows 10** desktop and **Linux Mint** laptop. Whenever I connect to Linux from Windows, the Windows key is transmitted perfectly. Whenever I connect from Linux, the super key is never transmitted, instead it opens start menu in Linux. Is it a bug or a feature? Is there a way to transmit the super key? It makes impossible to control anything effectively from Linux. The *Transmit hotkeys* option is turned on, of course.

I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia 64-bit with Cinnamon 4.4.5.

Comment: Which desktop manager are you using in Mint?

Comment: @roaima I am not sure what a desktop manager is (complete newbie in LInux), but if I get it right - the default one.

Comment: It is probably the desktop manager grabbing it. You can normally configure this. 

The desktop manager will be something like Kde-plasma, Gnome, Cinnamon (the default in Mint).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks, you pointed me in a right direction. I remapped menu to `Super + Tab` and Anydesk works fine for now. Weird behavior from Anydesk that super key causes linux menu to open. I tried using Realvnc and it transmits super key perfectly with the default settings (although it is sooo slow). If you care enough to post an answer to this question, I will accept it :)

Comment: Why not write up your own answer? (It is allowed) You won't get any points for being accepted. But send me a comment. If you do good job, then I will up-vote it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Did as you said. Just thought that it was your idea that helped me  so the answer should be yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Change the menu hotkey

It seems like when menu keyboard shortcut is set to `SuperL`, Cinnamon always catches the Super key before it gets to Anydesk. Changing the menu shortcut to something else allows to bypass this misbehavior (or a feature?) of Anydesk. I switched to `SuperL+Tab` and Anydesk even transmits this combination to my Windows remote desktop.

> Right click on menu icon > Configure > Panel tab> Behavior section > Keyboard shortcut

If you are looking for a solution without changing the menu hotkey, you can try [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/en/). It has a free license for a single user with up to 5 devices. However, it is much slower and more laggy than Anydesk.

I will look for other possible solutions and update the answer in case I find any.